# Sublime 3 returns "Unable to parse binding" when I add a key combination

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I entered this into "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap":

```
[
    {
        "key": ["option+f1"],
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": {"contents": "h2"}
    }   
]
```

And in the Console, Sublime 3 returned:

```
Unable to parse binding {args: {contents: h2}, command: insert_snippet, key: [option+f1]}
```

Of course, the key combination doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON key for specifying the key binding is `keys` and not `key`, even if there's only a single key in the list. Something like the following should do what you want:

```
    {
        "keys": ["option+f1"],
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": {"contents": "h2"}
    },
```